# C++ checking if an element is in my vector but getting failed to convert errors from eclipse

Tags: c++, vector, boolean

So below is my code. I am giving it several inputs but the important one is symbol and symbolList. symbolList is a 2D vector of strings. and the intent here is to check if symbol exists in symbolList and I am using the example from here: https://www.techiedelight.com/check-vector-contains-given-element-cpp/

Here is the code, error is on the if statement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include "windows.h"
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool check_input(string &orderID, char buysell, string &symbol, int &qty, string &error,  vector<vector<string>> &symbolList) {
    error="None";
    //omitted some irrelevant stuff
    if (std::find(symbolList.begin(), symbolList.end(), symbol) != symbolList.end()) {
        error= "wrong symbol";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But eclipse gives this error with my code and I don't see why:

```
could not convert 'std::find<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >*, std::vector<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > > >, std::basic_string<char> >((& symbolList)->std::vector<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >::begin(), (& symbolList)->std::vector<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >::end(), (*(const std::basic_string<char>*)(& symbol)))' from '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >*, std::vector<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > > >' to 'bool'
```

The compile error if I try to compile:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/include/c++/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of 'bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<_Value>::operator()(_Iterator) [with _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >*, std::vector<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > > >; _Value = const std::basic_string<char>]':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:120:14:   required from '_RandomAccessIterator std::__find_if(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Predicate, std::random_access_iterator_tag) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >*, std::vector<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > > >; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<const std::basic_string<char> >]'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:161:23:   required from '_Iterator std::__find_if(_Iterator, _Iterator, _Predicate) [with _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >*, std::vector<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > > >; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<const std::basic_string<char> >]'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:3938:28:   required from '_IIter std::find(_IIter, _IIter, const _Tp&) [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >*, std::vector<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > > >; _Tp = std::basic_string<char>]'
../src/oncemore.cpp:37:60:   required from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/include/c++/bits/predefined_ops.h:241:17: error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >' and 'const std::basic_string<char>')
```

Comment: You cannot `find` a `string` in a `vector<vector<string>> &symbolList`, just `vector<string>`s.

Comment: What do you mean by "symbol exists in symbolList"? One (or more) of the elements (`vector<string>`) contains the symbol to find?

Comment: [`std::find_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/) will be useful then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a `string` in a `vector<string>` but you are trying to find a `string` in a `vector<vector<string>>`, `find` can't do that.

It's not the only way to do it but my advice would be to use `find` in a loop.

```
for (const auto& row : symbolList) {
    if (std::find(row.begin(), row.end(), symbol) != row.end()) {
        error= "wrong symbol";
        return false;
    }
}
```

`row` is a reference to a `vector<string>` so you can find a string in that.